# Dynamic Endpoint WSO2 API Manager not updating the TO header

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Hi I have come across several blogs and forums and I am still unable to achieve the dynamic endpoint url update.My requirement is to update the API endpoint url based on the request parameter value. Hence I am trying to use Dynamic Endpoint feature in WSO2 Api Manager 2.6.0. I have uploaded the in flow sequence with the below code. But I still get the error.

In flow Code:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="admin--dynamicAPI_v1.0" trace ="enable">
   <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
   <log level="full">    
    <property name="headerTo" value="http://actualurl/tobe/redirected"/>
    <header name="To" expression="get-property('headerTo')"/>
    <property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS" value="http://actualurl/tobe/redirected"/>
 </log>
</sequence>
```

Error:

> *TID: [-1234] [] [2020-06-02 10:37:33,154]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To:
>   /service/1.0/*, MessageID:
>   urn:uuid:c341daaf-300e-4cdd-b6cd-ba0a7cb4b49d, Direction: request,
>   headerTo = http://actualurl/tobe/redirected, ENDPOINT_ADDRESS =
>   http://actualurl/tobe/redirected, Envelope: 
>   {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} TID: [-1234] []
>   [2020-06-02 10:37:33,156] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} -  The system cannot infer
>   the transport information from the /service/1.0/* URL.
>   {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} TID: [-1234] [] [2020-06-02
>   10:37:33,156] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - 
>   Unexpected error during sending message out
>   {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport
>   information from the /service/1.0/* URL.  at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:547)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:384)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.endpoints.DefaultEndpoint.send(DefaultEndpoint.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
>     at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:351)  at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)     at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have done that inside a log mediator. Can you try like below.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="admin--dynamicAPI_v1.0" trace ="enable">
   <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
   <property name="headerTo" value="http://actualurl/tobe/redirected"/>
   <header name="To" expression="get-property('headerTo')"/>
   <log level="full">    
      <property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS" expression="get-property('headerTo')"/>
   </log>
</sequence>
```